# Where is CMake's `FILE (GLOB` relative to?

Tags: cmake

If I do `FILE (GLOB "*.cpp")` where does it look? What is the working directory of the search? Is it the current source directory? This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere (although it is for `FILE (COPY`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search occurs in the current source directory, i.e. the directory of your `CMakeLists.txt`.

As a side remark regarding what you want to achieve with this, I would emphasize the [following](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/file.html):

> Note: We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files
>   from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source
>   is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when
>   to ask CMake to regenerate.

Comment: Thanks! And yeah I'm aware of the issues. This is for test files though so I think it is a reasonable compromise (doesn't matter too much if a test is omitted).

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify a RELATIVE path.  I'm not sure when the `RELATIVE` option was added, but it appears to be available from at least v3.0.2.
[image]

Comment: What is RELATIVE mean, I used the RELATIVE param, but occurred error.
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILE  LIST_DIRECTORIES false RELATIVE "/" "*.cpp")
the SOURCE_FILE variable has the true value,but get the error
"No SOURCES given to target: cpp-demo"

Comment: The `RELATIVE` key word means, that the results, you get are relative to that path.
For example, if you use `file(GLOB var "/project/src/*.c" RELATIVE "/project")` the result would look like this: `src/fileA.c` instead of `/project/src/fileA.c`

Answer (score 2):

The `FILE(GLOB globbing expression)` accepts paths in the globbing expression to. Thus you can include any path into the expression. The following example finds all files with extension dat in subfolder testdata:

`file(GLOB files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testdata/*.dat")`

Note: The usage of predefined path variables like CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR avoids any thinking about relative paths and made CMakeLists.txt more reusable and platform independent.

Bad:
`file(GLOB generatedSources "../build-arm/autocode/*.c")`

Good:
`file(GLOB generatedSources "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/autocode/*.c")`

Comment: True! Forgot to mention this in the other answer.

Comment: You have cleverly made your answer confusing! My entire question was about whether GLOB is already relative to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` so why didn't you just do `file(GLOB files "testdata/*.dat")`?

Comment: I recommend the usage of ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} to avoid usage of hard-coded path or any uncertainty whether it looks in the current folder or what is the current folder.